# (Processing) How to rotate player while moving and have a following camera?

Tags: java, math, rotation

I am trying to make the player to rotate but I just can't figure it out. I guess I haven't done my math, haha. I'll cut to the point.

I've been trying to get my player to face the mouse. If I don't move the player the rotate is fine but when I start moving, the player is moving in a circle.

In my class `Player` I have these data types:

```
PApplet parent; //So the program knows which PApplet to draw on, I guess.

private float x,y;

/*
 * For the Camera to follow the player
 */
private float cameraX;
private float cameraY;
```

and I have the `cameraFollow` method:

```
public void cameraFollow() {
    cameraX = x * -1 + parent.width / 2; // Calculates so the camera
    cameraY = y * -1 + parent.height / 2; // follows the player
    parent.translate(cameraX, cameraY); // Translate the window position
}
```

Now to the problem where I try to rotate my player facing the mouse. If I don't move the player the rotate is fine but when I move, then the player starts to move in circle when I move the mouse.

```
public void render() {
    //Rotate towards mouse
    float angle = PApplet.atan2(cameraY-parent.mouseY, cameraX-parent.mouseX);
    parent.pushMatrix();
    parent.translate(x,y);
    parent.rotate(angle-PApplet.HALF_PI);
    
    //Body
    parent.noStroke(); // no black lines around the ellipse
    parent.fill(playerColor.getRGB()); // Sets the color of the player
    parent.ellipseMode(PConstants.CENTER); // Makes the ellipse centered
    parent.ellipse(x, y, 20, 20); // creates an ellipse
    
    //Arms
    parent.stroke(0.5f);
    parent.fill(armsColor.getRGB());
    parent.ellipseMode(PConstants.CENTER);
    parent.ellipse(x-5, y-5, 5, 5);
    parent.ellipse(x+5, y-5, 5, 5);
    
    parent.popMatrix();
}
```

Comment: you are missing the description of the geometry ... what is what, which way your axises point ,... etc .. sketch an image (that usually half of the solution)... assuming this is 2D ? how is your camera and player represented (3x3 matrix or 2D position + angle/direction_vector)? you are rotating by `atan2` but I do not see a reset of the "matrix" before it (like setting identity matrix)... I see no actual angle nor direction of camera nor player in your code ...

Comment: This is 2D. The player is a circle with two circular hands and the camera is following the player instead of having a static camera with just the player moving.

Comment: do you have aspect ratio correction? that could mess up the angles. If yes you need to apply its inverse on the mouse position ...

Comment: Noo, I don’t. These are the only things in the game that has to do with the position of the player. 

I tried adding +y, +x and -y and -x to the angle but that turned out to be way wierder in the actual rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code so instead of:

```
float angle = PApplet.atan2(y-parent.mouseY, x-parent.mouseX);

//I did
float angle = PApplet.atan2(parent.mouseY-y, parent.mouseX-x);
```

and I saw that I had rotate at the completely wrong place so instead of having rotate before translate, I now have rotate after translate.

and before I had the ellipse assigned to the x and y coordinates and that's why the ellipse moved in circles. But now it's actually where the point of origin is.

```
public void render()
{
    //Rotate towards mouse
    float angle = PApplet.atan2(parent.mouseY-y, parent.mouseX-x);
    parent.pushMatrix();
    parent.translate(x,y);
    parent.rotate(angle+PApplet.HALF_PI);
    
    //Body
    parent.noStroke(); // no black lines around the ellipse
    parent.fill(playerColor.getRGB()); // Sets the color of the player
    parent.ellipseMode(PConstants.CENTER); // Makes the ellipse centered
    parent.ellipse(0, 0, 20, 20); // creates an ellipse
    
    //Arms
    parent.stroke(1);
    parent.fill(armsColor.getRGB());
    parent.ellipseMode(PConstants.CENTER);
    parent.ellipse(0-5, 0-5, 5, 5);
    parent.ellipse(0+5, 0-5, 5, 5);
    
    parent.popMatrix();
}
```

EDIT:
But now whenever I walk outside the window positions boundary the player will look away from the mouse. HMMM....

EDIT:
I Solved it by adding:

```
float angle = PApplet.atan2(parent.mouseY-cameraY-y, parent.mouseX-cameraX-x);
```

To the code!

Thanks again Spektre!